# Div tag alignment with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I'm sure this has been answered many times - but I've searched here with no luck...

I'm new to bootstrap (and div tags)... Here's what I've spent all day trying to figure out... I have 2 rows. The 1st row has 3 columns (1,2,3). The 2nd has 2 columns (4,5) . I'm trying to simply "allow" column "3" to extend into and beside column "5" - currently column 4 & 5 get pushed down below the end of 3...

Column "3" may contain an article or contact form - not sure yet- either way I need the flexibility...

I have successfully done this by nesting 4 into 1 & 5 into 2... but when I view in mobile view column 3 gets pushed to the end of section5... I want 3 to remain number 3 in the mobile vertical view list..

Does Bootstrap have something built into CSS to accomodate?
Are multiple 'containers' required?
I'd rather not add CSS, but if that's the only way so be it... Thanks!

My code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <h2>section1 </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <h2>section2 </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <h2>section3 </h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-4">section4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">section5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3 it may help with you question that you are asking.

Comment: Your explanation is quite vague. You may want to do up a quick illustration for what you are trying to explain. Will help us out greatly.

Comment: I just drew a diagram for you - but SO says I need a "10" to post an image... The 3rd column in my row is pushing down the lower row - I'm trying to resolve this while being consistent with the mobile view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking to accomplish:

## [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lF0cSWrdNq#)

First, there is no .row-fluid class in Bootstrap 3.  For this design, you'll need just a single `.row` and you'll use the helper class `.pull-right` on the section 3 element as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 pull-right">
      <h2>Section 3</h2> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <h2>Section 4</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <h2>Section 5</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, what's going on here is that the col-* classes have `float: left` applied to them by default.  That means that if you were to have very long content in the 3rd column, when the remaining two columns wrap, there would be a gap between them and the first two columns, equal to the height of the 3rd column.  We can fix this by telling the third column to float right instead. That's what the class `.pull-right` does -- it applies `float: right` to the element on which it's used.

When the third column is floated to the right, the 4th and 5th columns can sit neatly right below the left floated columns 1 and 2 at the md and lg breakpoints (991px and up).  At the sm and xs breakpoints though, the source order is honored and section 3 displays in the proper position below section 2 and above section 4.

Finally, using a single row allows all of the columns to wrap at 12-grid units.

**If your content is dynamic or uneven in length, you can use the technique shown in the Bootply of nesting columns 1 and 2 together in a single column, as well as columns 4 and 5.

If you're new to Bootstrap, I encourage you take a look at my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899715/bootstrap-balancing-bullet-columns/23912463#23912463) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27013429/proper-bootstrap-grid/27015338#27015338), to help you understand and visualize the grid better.

Comment: That's what I needed to get going - thank you! Will read through your two links... much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation... As I think you can tell I assumed the 12 grid unit limit had to be 'honored' in each row... Now I see you are wrapping column 4 and 5 ... To your Nesting comment - I was able to do this previously but then, of course, the mobile grip units were not displayed in the proper sequence.. I'll assume your extended wrap technique is acceptable in the Bootstrap/HTML5 world... You've helped me understand a fundamental design need that I was not able to understand/locate on youtube or elsewhere for many hours... thanks again - I think I'm now off and running!

Comment: URG - now with <div class="col-md-4 pull-right"> wrapped around a contactus form - a user can not make a text entry unless the page is in full screen - once a user reduced the screen or views on a tablet an entry into the form is not possible... any further suggestions would be awesome - thanks!

Comment: I updated the Bootply and the answer.  This works, though it doesn't seem like the most elegant response to me.  I will take a closer look in a couple of hours.